# How to get names of specific nodes depending on taints in K8S

Tags: json, kubernetes, jsonpath

In a Kubernetes cluster, I have a few nodes, master and workers. I want to get the name of nodes which have no taints on them. I know I need to get them using the jsonpath and adding conditions in it, but not sure how exactly.

What can I try next? Taints are in spec and names of the nodes are obviously in metadata, so how can I approach this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `go-template` to do this:

**Example:**

```
kubectl get node  -o go-template='{{range $element := .items}}{{if (ne (len (or $element.spec.taints ""))  0)}}{{$element.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

**In more readable format:**

```
kubectl get node  -o go-template='{{ range $element := .items }}
                                {{- if (ne (len (or $element.spec.taints ""))  0) -}}
                                    {{ $element.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}
                                {{- end -}}
                            {{ end }}'
```

**Working**:

- using `range,` we will loop over the items. In this case, it's the
  nodes.
- using the `len` function, we will calculate the length of the
  list holding all the taints.
- Used `or` inside the `len` function for defaulting it to "0" if no taint is found.
- If the taint len is **not equal**(`ne`) to zero, printing the element name(ie, node name)
- you can `flip` the `ne` to `eq` to reverse the behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to shorten this? I know of this method where we can check each term by using special characters like (?(@ == ...)) where the ? is the equivalent of check if and @ is the equivalent of all terms in that particular level. Is it possible to use that notation in this case?

Comment: @SamarthGoyal, `jsonpath` is not the right tool for this requirement. You will have to pipe the results with other tools. like `jq`, `awk`, grep` etc.